# subset in an even bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G=(V,U,E)$ be a bipartite graph, i.e. $V,U$ are sets of vertices s.t. $E\subseteq V\times U$.

It is also given that every vertex (both in $U$ and in $V$) has an even degree.

**Prove** that there exist some subset $E'\subseteq E\ $ s.t. in the graph $G'=(V,U,E')$ the degree of each vertex is **exactly** half of its degree in $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A graph $G$ in which every vertex has even degree can be decomposed into cycles.  (That is, $E(G)$ is a disjoint union of cycles.)  If $G$ is bipartite, what has to be true about those cycles?

Comment: Every vertex of the graph must be in an even number of cycles? and then we can take the cycles and leave half of the edges in a yes no operation, like taking a flower and taking one out and leaving the next?

Comment: @TrueTopologist A vertex need not be in an even number of cycles, but your idea about alternately taking and deleting edges is correct.

Comment: Oh thank you. So it will work too because each vertex will stay with one instead of two edges in each cycle, right?